# InterfaceBuilder with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, uiview, avfoundation, swift2

I have tried dragging and dropping a `UIView` into my storyboard, setting that to type `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, but it won't autocomplete and it won't work.

How can I create a view in my storyboard, where I can load that `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` in? Should I use `UIView` or a different `UI*` element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIView`. But since `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is a subclass of `CALayer` class. So you have to add `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` object as `addSublayer`: but not as a `addSubView` to layer of UIView object.

Example:

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *cameraPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    CALayer *viewLayer = self.cameraPreviewView.layer;

    cameraPreviewLayer.frame = self.cameraPreviewView.bounds;
    [viewLayer addSublayer:cameraPreviewLayer];

    self.cameraPreviewLayer = cameraPreviewLayer;
```

You can rewrite the same in `Swift`.

Comment: But does that mean I can place a `UIView` in IB, hook it up to the controller file and then add the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` to that  `UIView`? As a subLayer?